# Triggering multiple actions for single event-listener(on-click) in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm not able to trigger multiple actions for single event listeners in javascript. I'm working on google chrome extensions. So when I tried to run this code below it doesn't work.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
             var action_url = "javascript:window.print();";
             chrome.tabs.update({url: action_url});
             chrome.tabs.executeScript({
             code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"'
         });
  });
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What actions do you want to trigger. Can you be specific about your expectation?

Comment: Obviously change the order of commands: first change the color, then invoke the print dialog. Also check your background page console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks i got the logic how its done....

Comment: @SriharshaKeshav Please answer your own question now that you solved your issue

Answer (score -1):

I had interchanged the code for some other extension and was trying to execute wrong extension. So I made changes accordingly such that I put right code in the extension which I wanted to run.